# How to query an SQL Server through a batch file if the column I want contains a special character in the name?

Tags: sql, sql-server, batch-file, sqlcmd

I am trying to create a batch file that will automatically fetch some data for me. I have the SQL query ready and working, but only if I run it manually through the command prompt. If I try to run the same query through a batch file, then it errors out. I would also like to point out that I'm exporting to a CSV file and my data contains commas, so I'm wrapping the column with doubled double quotes. My query is:

```
sqlcmd -S myserver -U user -P pass -s "," -W -o MyData.csv -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON; SELECT '""' + Descripción + '""' AS Descripcion FROM table"
```

The problem lies with the special character:

> ó

The error message is:

> Msg 102 Level 15 State 1 Server myserver Line 1 Incorrect Syntax near '+'

For some reason this works perfectly when ran through the command prompt... Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance

Comment: try using a code page that supports `ó` such as 65001

Comment: If the same command works OK from command-line, then the .BAT file is the problem, so you could blame the text editor. Are you using Notepad+? It is infamous for save files *not* in Ansi encoding by default...

Comment: on my system cmd reads `ó` as `├│` with the default code page being 850 [from a batch file  using UTF-8]

Comment: @Aacini I'm using plain old notepad to write the bat file. Which program would you recommend?

Comment: Nowadays, `notepad.exe` in Windows, saves as UTF-8 by default. Bach files should not use UTF-8.

Comment: In Notepad use "Save as" and then, in "Encoding", select Ansi...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @T3RR0R for pointing out the code page solution. Used `chcp 65001` in the bat file before the query and now it works!